# Bug??? with loading data from model to js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I made a JS function that creates selector tags for the clients of a hotel room. So if my room capacity equals to 4, it creates dynamicly 4 selectors. In my selector tag there are options containing the clients. The options values are the ID of the client, but when I set my options.text to Client's name for example I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: changeFunc is not defined
> at HTMLSelectElement.onchange
> Here is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFunc() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('selector2');
    while (elements.length > 0) {
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
    var selector = document.getElementById('selector');
    var selectedValue = selector.value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
    @foreach (var item in Model.Rooms)
    {
            <text>
            if (@item.RoomID == selectedValue)
            {
                var selectedValue2 = @item.Capacity;
            }
            </text>
    }
    var inputContainer = document.getElementById('for-input');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue2; i++)
    {
        var selector2 = inputContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("select"));
        selector2.className = "selector2";
        @foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
        {
            <text>
                var optionz = document.createElement("option");
                optionz.value = @item.ID;
                optionz.text = @item.Name; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                selector2.appendChild(optionz);
            </text>

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my div that contains all the selectors:

```
<div id="for-input"></div>
```

The strange thing is that if I change item.Name to item.ID or item.phoneNumber, it works. So that means it supports integers only for some reason. Then I tried setting the optionz.text to "Hello world" and it worked too!!! That just blew my mind :X

I tought that I have some problem with the model and tried to load the clients into a different selector:

```
<select>
@foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
{
    <option value="@item.Name">@item.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

It worked too!!!

Where the problem comes from???

Please don't judge me too much, it's my first code in JS! I'm learning it rn :)

Thanks in advance!

Updated! Here is my onchange handler:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Reservations2.RoomId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Reservations2.RoomId" onchange="changeFunc();" class="form-select" id="selector">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Rooms)
        {
            <option value="@item.RoomID">Room @item.RoomID with capacity of@item.Capacity</option>
        }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Reservations2.RoomId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: some code is not posted yet, I don't see where you register the `onchange` handler for any `<select>` element. The error is obviously related to that.

Comment: I just updated my post with the required code!

Comment: King King any ideas bro?

Comment: sorry, I'm not so sure. You should make sure that the `changeFunc` in defined in a scope that is accessible by your HTML. The error shows clearly that `changeFunc` is not recognized (not defined)

Comment: Why then it's working when I change from "item.Name" to "item.ID" or "item.phoneNumber". It doesn't make sence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was so simple! I just needed to put the value in quotes...